# Package.json not found while running inside docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-machine

I have a very simple website built by ExpressJS. I run Docker Quick Start terminal and go to the working directory.

This is the result of `ls` command

```
app.js  bin/  node_modules/  package.json  public/  routes/  views/
```

When I issue the command below, I get "No such file or directory" error:

```
docker run -p 8080:3000 -v $(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node npm start
```

[image]

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit

What am I missing here?

Comment: can you share you DockerFile or i will suggest to use this dockerfile https://github.com/Adiii717/Node_DockerFile

Comment: and 2nd thing you dont need to start npm through terminal with docker run command you can start npm inside docker file then it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you checked mark your Windows drives in order to accessible for the Docker Engine by going to `docker settings` => `Shared Drives`.

Also define the absolute path instead of `$(pwd)` i.e. `d:\express:/var/www`. The same issue I confronted a couple weeks ago where I resolved using the above approach.